# How can I quickly set the sound output device on Big Sur?

Tags: catalina, audio, big-sur

Before the update to Big Sur I could <kbd>ALT</kbd>+click on the sound icon in the menubar to change output devices (as described in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/111682/24324)).

Now, on macOS 11.0.1, when I <kbd>ALT</kbd>+click on the sound icon I only see the internal speakers, while I have more output devices:

[image]

The Sound window in the System Preferences *does* show all output devices and lets me select them:

[image]

How can I quickly switch from Internal Speakers to the USB audio devices I have (like in Catalina)?

Comment: If your only want to change the _output device_ you can simply just single _left-click_ the _volume icon_ in the **menu bar**. Using an _option-click_ enables the selection of either _output device_ or _input device_. That said, I'm running a clean install of **macOS Big Sur** (11.0.1) and whether I single _left-click_ or _option-click_ the _volume icon_ in the **menu bar**, it show the same _devices_ as in **System Preferences** > **Sound** > **Output|Input**. So I'm seeing the exact same behavior as in **macOS Catalina** and earlier. I know that doesn't directly help, but it what I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the issue was, but a restart solved the problem: the output devices in the sound menu now match those in System Preferences.